# Unable to export data from mongodb in robo 3T. Unexpected indentifier issue

Tags: mongodb, export, export-to-csv

I am trying to export data from mongo cloud from Robo 3T by using below command, but getting unexpected idenitifer issue on execution.

mongoexport --host "HOST" --port 27017 --username "user" --password "password" --collection collectioname --db dbname --out OUTPUTFILE.csv --type=csv

Could anyone help here please .

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Tableplus](https://tableplus.com/linux) as your GUI for mongodb, you can directly do import/export from there. It'a all in one GUI supported for mac and linux OS.